# Conditionals with normal order evaluation

Tags: lambda-calculus, evaluation-strategies

From what I've read, conditionals (like the **cond** statement in lisp) do not need to be primitive if normal order evaluation is used.

Using lambda calculus and normal order evaluation, how can you emulate **if** and **cond** statements?

```
(cond (<p1> <e1>)
      (<p2> <e2>)
      ...
      (<pn> <en>))

(if <predicate> <consequent> <alternative>)
```

References to SICP are welcome, though a simpler example would be helpful.

(Definitions of **cond** and **if** taken from [Section 1.1.6 of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.6))

Comment: Church encoded booleans would be the thing to look at here. Note that cond is easy to emulate using nested ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the church notation:

**TRUE**: $\lambda ab.a$

**FALSE**: $\lambda ab.b$

**IF**: $\lambda pxy.pxy$

By passing a church boolean as a predicate to the **IF** function, we choose one of two alternatives. **TRUE** chooses the first argument passed to it, and **FALSE** chooses the second.

We can derive **COND** by folding **IF** across a list of (condition, result) pairs

You can find wikipedia's explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans), as well as assorted lambda calculus derivations [here](http://jwodder.freeshell.org/lambda.html).